# How to add a background image in JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jtextarea

I did exactly according to the excellent guide but it does not work, I want to click a button that will change the background of the program. I would love to make the picture change

Code Guide https://stackhowto.com/how-to-set-background-image-in-java-swing/

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display an image in the background");
        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("background.png");
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea()
        {
             Image img = icon.getImage();
            // instance initializer
            {setOpaque(false);}
            public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
                super.paintComponent(graphics);
            }
        };
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the part that does not work?

Comment: You may read https://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=swing.async

Comment: the part has not work is the picture I run the program and the Panel is open empty...

Comment: Are you sure the image has been loaded?

Comment: no.. @Jean-BaptisteYunes

Comment: I need help....

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès *"Are you sure the image has been loaded?"* OP: *"No"*. Then some basic debugging is called for (*before* asking here). After `Image img = icon.getImage();`, display `img` in a `JOptionPane`.